# Karate on iOS Simulator is throwing com.intuit.karate - java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Tags: automation, appium, ui-automation, karate, appium-ios

Karate execution stops with an exception before even time Simulator gets initiated. 
After simulator is initiated, can't perform any action as execution is stopped.

Please help because I am not able to perform any action on simulator.

I tried giving waits in feature file as well as karate-config file, but nothing worked.

```js
      #Capabilities
 * def session = {  desiredCapabilities: {  platformName: "iOS", platformVersion: "13.4", deviceName: "iPhone 11", automationName: "XCUITest", app: "Mobile.app" } }

 #Configure driver
   * configure driver = { type: 'ios', webDriverSession: '#(session)' , webDriverUrl: 'http://localhost:4723/wd/hub'}
  
  
   
 #Initialize driver and Open application on simulator
 Given driver {}
 
 And delay(120000)

 #Open sim and perform action
 
 #Enter Username
 And input("//TextField[@name='Username']", 'sampleuser')
 
 #Enter Password
 And input("//TextField[@name='Password']", 'sample@123')
```

Below is the exception detail.

```js
15:57:11.812 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[read] I/O error: Read timed out"
15:57:11.812 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-0: Close connection
15:57:11.813 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-0: Shutdown connection
15:57:11.813 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Connection discarded
15:57:11.814 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection released: [id: 0][route: {}->http://localhost:4723][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 5; total allocated: 0 of 10]
15:57:11.814 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out, http call failed after 30028 milliseconds for URL: http://localhost:4723/wd/hub/session
15:57:11.814 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - http request failed: 
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
15:57:11.820 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - driver config / start failed: 
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out, options: {type=ios, webDriverSession={desiredCapabilities={platformName=iOS, platformVersion=13.4, deviceName=iPhone 11, automationName=XCUITest, app=Mobile.app}}, webDriverUrl=http://localhost:4723/wd/hub, target=null}
com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: 
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
 at com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioContext.clientInvoke(ScenarioContext.java:687)
 at com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioContext.method(ScenarioContext.java:735)
 at com.intuit.karate.Http.post(Http.java:125)
 at com.intuit.karate.Http.post(Http.java:130)
 at com.intuit.karate.Http.post(Http.java:120)
 at com.intuit.karate.driver.WebDriver.<init>(WebDriver.java:58)
 at com.intuit.karate.driver.appium.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:45)
 at com.intuit.karate.driver.appium.IosDriver.<init>(IosDriver.java:14)
 at com.intuit.karate.driver.appium.IosDriver.start(IosDriver.java:20)
 at com.intuit.karate.driver.DriverOptions.start(DriverOptions.java:283)
 at com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioContext.driver(ScenarioContext.java:967)
 at com.intuit.karate.StepActions.driver(StepActions.java:392)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at com.intuit.karate.core.Engine.executeStep(Engine.java:153)
 at com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioExecutionUnit.execute(ScenarioExecutionUnit.java:219)
 at com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioExecutionUnit.run(ScenarioExecutionUnit.java:297)
 at com.intuit.karate.core.FeatureExecutionUnit.run(FeatureExecutionUnit.java:195)
 at com.intuit.karate.junit5.FeatureNode.lambda$0(FeatureNode.java:80)
 at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.DynamicTestTestDescriptor.lambda$execute$0(DynamicTestTestDescriptor.java:52)
 at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:125)
 at org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.InvocationInterceptor.interceptDynamicTest(InvocationInterceptor.java:158)
 at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.DynamicTestTestDescriptor.lambda$execute$1(DynamicTestTestDescriptor.java:58)
 at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoid$0(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:76)
 at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:104)
 at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:62)
 at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:43)
 at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:35)
 at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.DynamicTestTestDescriptor.execute(DynamicTestTestDescriptor.java:57)
 at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.DynamicTestTestDescriptor.execute(DynamicTestTestDescriptor.java:31)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask$DefaultDynamicTestExecutor.execute(NodeTestTask.java:198)
 at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
 at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
 at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
 at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
 at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$11$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:373)
 at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
 at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
 at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
 at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
 at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
 at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
 at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
 at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachOrdered(ReferencePipeline.java:423)
 at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.DynamicContainerTestDescriptor.execute(DynamicContainerTestDescriptor.java:65)
 at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.DynamicContainerTestDescriptor.execute(DynamicContainerTestDescriptor.java:33)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask$DefaultDynamicTestExecutor.execute(NodeTestTask.java:198)
 at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:159)
 at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestFactoryTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$1(TestFactoryTestDescriptor.java:106)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
 at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestFactoryTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestFactoryTestDescriptor.java:93)
 at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
 at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
 at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
 at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
 at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
 at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
 at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
 at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:86)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `httpConfig : { readTimeout: 120000 }` to the driver config.

Here is an example: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/develop/examples/mobile-test/src/test/java/android/android.feature

Explained here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#configure-driver

Comment: Thank you Pete, that worked, very much appreciate your work. :)